# How to create multiple ListViews with fragments(if possible, with ListFragment) in Android

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to Android. Actually I want to create three listviews with the help of fragments. Is it possible? if possible then please give some reference. Any help in this regard will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want make a fragment with 3 listview?

Just write a YourFragment extends Fragment, which with a layout contain 3 listviews.

I think ListFragment is useless in this situation, it just like ListActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want three ListFragments, it goes something like this.

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="3dp">

<fragment class="com.fragtest.Fragment1"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<fragment class="com.fragtest.Fragment2"
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<fragment class="com.fragtest.Fragment3" 
    android:id="@+id/fragment3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then an xml for each fragment.

fragment1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then finally some code to hang it all together.  Your main activity:

```
public class ListFragmentExampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

And a class for each fragment to populate the lists... Fragment1.java:

```
public class JobFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ScheduleDBAdapter mDBHelper;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mDBHelper = new ScheduleDBAdapter(getActivity());
        mDBHelper.open();
        fillData();
    }

    private void fillData() {
        Cursor jobsCursor = mDBHelper.fetchAllJobs();
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(jobsCursor);
        String[] from = new String[] { ScheduleDBAdapter.JOB_NUMBER,
                ScheduleDBAdapter.JOB_PART };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ListItem1, R.id.ListItem2 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter jobs = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.listlayoutdouble, jobsCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(jobs);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!